# Should I use same google adsense ad block on different site

Tags: google, google-adsense

I have couple of sites Like `http://domain.com`, `http://sub1.domain.com`, `http://sub2.domain.com` and suppose i have a ad block 300x250 Can i use the ads to all those sites or i should make different ad block to use in every site? Does it affect the ad relevancy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same ad block will display different adverts relevant to the content on each page it displays on. This works on a page-level, so if your site was:

`http://www.fishing.com` (about fishing), it would display ads that are relevant to fishing. If you have `http://www.fishing.com/piano` (about piano...), then you would get ads relevant to piano, from the same ad block (code).

Comment: So, i don't have to worry about making different ad block for each site right? i can just use same ad block over and over on my all sites?

Comment: Yep. :) Unless you want different size blocks, of course.